# watch kit extension connect using SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, rows, watchkit

I need help how to connect my SQLite database to my watchkit app extension. Im not much familiar in using sqlite with cell rows. Any easy sample codes will be a great help thanks. Below are sample arrays i used for example.

```
#import "ICBQuoteSource.h"


@implementation ICBQuoteSource

+(NSArray *)quoteDictionary {
NSMutableArray *quotes = [NSMutableArray new];

[quotes addObject:@{@"characterImage": @"moss", @"characterName": @"Moss", @"quote": @"I came here to drink milk and kick ass... and I've just finished my milk."}];
[quotes addObject:@{@"characterImage": @"roy", @"characterName": @"Roy", @"quote": @"Hello, IT, have you tried turning it off and on again?"}];
[quotes addObject:@{@"characterImage": @"moss", @"characterName": @"Moss", @"quote": @"Did you see that ludicrous display last night?"}];
[quotes addObject:@{@"characterImage": @"denholm", @"characterName": @"Denholm", @"quote": @"That's the sort of place this is, Jen. A lot of sexy people not doing much work and having affairs."}];
[quotes addObject:@{@"characterImage": @"moss", @"characterName": @"Moss", @"quote": @"This Jen is the Internet"}];

return [NSArray arrayWithArray:quotes];
}

@end

#import "InterfaceController.h"
#import "ICBQuoteSource.h"
#import "rowController.h"

@interface InterfaceController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *quotes;

@end


@implementation InterfaceController

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context
{
[super awakeWithContext:context];

// Get quotes
self.quotes = [ICBQuoteSource quoteDictionary];

// Set number of table Row
[self.table setNumberOfRows:self.quotes.count withRowType:@"Row Controller"];

// Set row properties
for (NSDictionary *quote in self.quotes) {

    rowController *quoteRow = [self.table rowControllerAtIndex:[self.quotes indexOfObject:quote]];
    [quoteRow.englishTxtLabel setText:quote[@"characterName"]];
    [quoteRow.translationTxtLabel setText:quote[@"quote"]];
}
}




- (void)willActivate {
// This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
[super willActivate];
}

- (void)didDeactivate {
// This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
[super didDeactivate];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually stated what the problem is...so let me attempt to guess. I'm assuming that the rows are not showing up properly in your table. What I would suggest trying is moving your row set up logic into `willActivate`. This is something I found when working with tables in Xcode 6.2b5. You would not get the appropriate behavior in `awakeWithContext(:)`.

Hopefully that helps lead you in the right direction. If this isn't the actual problem you are having, then please edit your question and I'll edit my answer accordingly.